# Different output in visual when using VAR in DAX, versus hardcoding value

Tags: powerbi, dax

The average price is 28.87 and I want to calculate and visualize the number of products with a price higher than 28.87 on a row by row basis. The total number is 25.

In the table visual below, I only see the values above average when using the hardcoded value (_avg2), and not when using the formula (_avg). Please refer to the measure below. I only switch around _avg and _avg2 in line 9 in the two columns.

```
countAvg = 

VAR _avg = AVERAGE( ( Products[UnitPrice] ) ) 
VAR _avg2 = 28.87

VAR _aboveAvg  = 
     CALCULATE(
        COUNT( Products[ProductName] ) , 
        FILTER( Products , [Unit Price] > ( _avg  ) ) )

RETURN _aboveAvg
```

Below you can see the difference in a snapshot of the visual.

Question: Is my defined variable _avg incorrect in terms of making it visible on a row level (evaluation context)? Anyhow, what should it be to make it work? Having it as a hardcoded value (_avg2) is not useful.

Thanks in advance!

[image: Visual]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing the filter context of the _avg formula:

```
VAR _avg = CALCULATE(AVERAGE( Products[UnitPrice] ), ALLSELECTED(PRODUCTS)  )
```